# Numpy and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, python-2.7

I'm tired to import cv and numpy and get errors. I started importing cv and I got this error:

> ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in <module>
>     File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
>       from cv2.cv import *
>   ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

So I installed numpy on Ubuntu using:

```
apt-get install python-numpy
```

So when I import numpy I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in <module>
>         File "numpy/**init**.py", line 127, in <module>
>           raise ImportError(msg)
>       ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
>               its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
>               your python intepreter from there.

I really need help. I'm using Python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better that use some package management tool such like pip to install numpy.
For example,

```
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing wrong with installing common dependencies using your operating system's package manager, remember using **pip** means your synaptic updates won't update your Python libraries and pip won't leverage the dependencies already taken care of by aptitude. For python packages with C extensions like numpy and opencv its probably better to use apt-get.

In Ubuntu you can install both dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-opencv
```

The actual Python error you are getting indicates what is wrong, namely that you are executing from within the numpy source directory, or have a file named `numpy.py` in your current directory which is confusing things at import time. Try change into an empty directory, start Python import your libraries:

```
import numpy
import cv
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Man you helped me too but the other guy answer a objective question sorry about the accept ;)